# How to read a paragraph from a text file as a single string in Javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to read a paragraph then display it in my webpage. 
I actually have a text file that have many paragraphs.
I want to read each  paragraph and display it on the screen of my webpage.
Thanks

Comment: JS has no file operations. you cannot "read a file" in JS.

Comment: You need to specify how the text file splits each paragraph. Also, you need to load the file into JS somehow. Either you set up a web server that serves it so that you can fetch it with Ajax, or you can bundle it into the webpage where you can retrieve it from JS/jQuery. You should also describe how this text file is structured in order to know how to parse out the different paragraphs.

Comment: @Marc B, usually not but now it does. try with node.js https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs/

Comment: @TheDefinitionist in the context of the browser it does not... node does not run in the browser

Comment: wut? who said I'm pointing at browsers - doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a server-side programming language like Node.js, PHP, Java, etc to complete this. It would access your filesystem to retrieve the file data and then send a response back to the browser.

It might look something like this...

Javascript:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = 'text.txt';
var contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);
// send output
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
  $myfile = 'text.txt';
  readfile($myfile);
  //send output
?>
```